# Is it haram to use a windows that is installed or bootable through a pirated Windows?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, piracy

I have downloaded Windows from the official website and now I want to make it bootable to a usb. I have a option to make bootable through my friend's laptop which has pirated Windows. I'm confused is it haram and sin to use it. 
Around me mostly people use pirated Windows so I'm very confused how to find a person who has not pirated Windows. And may be if I found a person with not pirated Windows it's chances he booted through a pirated Windows. 
This chain may would be in a form of continuous sins.

Answer (score 0):

Allah has created the world.He has placed many options and possibilities.Many different paths for every person.They can be seem or different.
You could do linux or be the greater person and buy windows.
Just the intention of doing something right is enough.